# Ensure Spark DataGrid item is visible

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

Is there a way to make sure the selected item is visible in the Spark DataGrid?

.

**Context**
I have a data grid bound to an array collection. I receive remotely a service that gives me a ID (string) of an object that is in the collection. Using just the string I loop through the collection to find the item that matches the string. I find the object by it's ID. Now I have the object I want to select in the datagrid. I can set the

```
dataGrid.selectedItem = object;
```

Now I need to make sure it's visible. I do not have the row or column index.

.

**Update**
Using the answer below I've complimented it with this function:

```
    /**
     * Ensures the item is visible (for spark data grid)
     **/
    public function ensureItemIsVisibleInSparkDataGrid(datagrid:spark.components.DataGrid, item:Object):void {
        var list:IList = datagrid.dataProvider;
        var length:int = list.length;
        var itemFound:Boolean;
        var object:Object;
        var index:int;

        for (var i:int;i<length;i++) {
            object = list.getItemAt(i);

            if (object==item) {
                itemFound = true;
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (itemFound) {
            datagrid.ensureCellIsVisible(index);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called [`ensureCellIsVisible()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#ensureCellIsVisible%28%29). You need to know that row and column of the item in question. To get this to work you'd need to listen for the [`selectionChange`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#event%3aselectionChange) event then calculate the row and column of the currently selected item.

Comment: I saw that method but like you said you have to determine the row and column which I don't know how to do. I have only the item (previously selected). I do not have the selected index.

Comment: You don't have [selectedCell](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#selectedCell)?